# Question on log-in on other SE forums

Tags: support

If I want to log in in a different SE forum, eg sceptics, 
do I need to log in there separately, with a new identity?

Comment: who downvotes a _support_ request?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to log in once with the same openID to create the account, it will then be linked to your other accounts automatically (and, since you have >200 rep here, you'll get a 100 rep start bonus). **edit** You can also use two different openIDs in case you want the accounts to remain separated

Comment: Thank You. Did I use an openID when I logged in here first? Let me see...

Comment: There's no way to log in to Stack Exchange without an OpenID of some sort

Comment: @Georg I can see you have logged in with your Gmail account; just use "log in with Google" option on the other site.

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot, problem was that I had forgotten how that worked when I logged in here in January :=)